# Run useEffect only one when a special property changed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I want to update render when a special property changes. This property income from parents. I Made a useState called loader to handle codes when I have data or not. if the loader is false, my code calls API and if it is true render data.
First of all I use useEffect this way. It didn't update render

```
useEffect(() => {
callApi();
}, []);
```

After that I used useEffect this way. `props.coordinates` is a property that my code should update after it changes.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    callApi();
    setLoader(false);
  }, [props.coordinates]);
```

But my codes are in loops, and my API key was blocked.
Could you let me know what my mistake is ?

This my component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import ForcastHour from "./ForcastHour";
import "./WeatherHourlyForcast.css";

const WeatherHourlyForcast = (props) => {
  const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);
  const [hourlyForcastData, setHourlylyForcastData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    callApi();
    setLoader(false);
  }, [props.coordinates]);

  const showHourlyForcast = (response) => {
    console.log("showHourlyForcast", response.data.hourly);
    setHourlylyForcastData(response.data.hourly);
    setLoader(true);
  };

  function callApi() {
    let latitude = props.coordinates.lat;
    let longitude = props.coordinates.lon;
    const apiKey = "23422500afd990f6bd64b60f46cf509a";
    let units = "metric";
    let apiUrl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${apiKey}&units=${units}`;
    axios.get(apiUrl).then(showHourlyForcast);
    console.log("hourly", apiUrl);
  }

  if (loader) {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <div className="row">
            {hourlyForcastData.map(function (hourlyforcast, index) {
              if (index < 4 && index > 0) {
                return (
                  <div
                    className="col-4 box-weather my-auto text-center"
                    key={index}
                  >
                    <ForcastHour data={hourlyforcast} />
                  </div>
                );
              }
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <div className="row">
            {hourlyForcastData.map(function (hourlyforcast, index) {
              if (index < 7 && index > 3) {
                return (
                  <div
                    className="col-4 box-weather my-auto text-center"
                    key={index}
                  >
                    <ForcastHour data={hourlyforcast} />
                  </div>
                );
              }
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    callApi();
    return null;
  }
};

export default WeatherHourlyForcast;
```

Comment: You need to `callApi ()` in your `useEffect ` method

Comment: You can't issue side-effect in the render return of a React component, especially if it triggers rerenders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While adding dependencies array to the end of `useEffect` (or any other hook...), each render if the value is not equal to the prev one, the hook will run again.

Because `props.coordinates` is an object, and in JS `objA != objA == true`, even if the properties didn't change, React can't know that.

My suggestion is to use the values themselves (assuming they're strings either numbers and so on)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await callApi();
      setLoader(false);
   })()
  }, [props.coordinates.lat, props.coordinates.lon]);
```

Another thing that you might encounter is `setLoader(false)` will be called before `callApi` will be finished, therefore added async behaviour to the hook

Comment: This solution did worked and decrease logs. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can write your component likes this and call the APIs when the component mount. The API calls happens when the `lat`, `lon` values are changed.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import ForcastHour from "./ForcastHour";
import "./WeatherHourlyForcast.css";

const WeatherHourlyForcast = (props) => {
  const { coordinates : { lat, lon } } = props;
  const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);
  const [hourlyForcastData, setHourlylyForcastData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    callApi();
  }, [lat, lon]); //It's call the API's when the lat, lon values are changed

  const callApi = () => {
    setLoader(true);
    const latitude = lat;
    const longitude = lon;
    const apiKey = "23422500afd990f6bd64b60f46cf509a";
    const units = "metric";
    const apiUrl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${apiKey}&units=${units}`;
    axios.get(apiUrl).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      console.log(response.status);
      console.log(response.statusText);
      console.log(response.headers);
      console.log(response.config);
      console.log("showHourlyForcast", response.data.hourly);
      setHourlylyForcastData(response.data.hourly);
      setLoader(false);
    });
  };

  if (loader) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Loading...</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-6">
        <div className="row">
          {hourlyForcastData.map(function (hourlyforcast, index) {
            if (index < 4 && index > 0) {
              return (
                <div
                  className="col-4 box-weather my-auto text-center"
                  key={index}
                >
                  <ForcastHour data={hourlyforcast} />
                </div>
              );
            }
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-6">
        <div className="row">
          {hourlyForcastData.map(function (hourlyforcast, index) {
            if (index < 7 && index > 3) {
              return (
                <div
                  className="col-4 box-weather my-auto text-center"
                  key={index}
                >
                  <ForcastHour data={hourlyforcast} />
                </div>
              );
            }
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default WeatherHourlyForcast;
```

Comment: I tried this. but I think this is a problem. on load of page it didn't call API and nothing was sent to map for rendering.

Comment: Had your correct way to pass `props` from parent to child component